# pandasで単独の要素に値を代入する際のiatとilocの違いについて ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Tags: python, pandas

単独の要素に値を代入する際のiatとilocの違いについて

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan, 2], [1, 3], [4, 6]], columns=['A', 'B'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['aaa', 'bbb'], [1, 3], [4, 6]], columns=['A', 'B'])
```

```
   A    B
0   NaN 2
1   1.0 3
2   4.0 6
```

```
   A    B
0   aaa bbb
1   1   3
2   4   6
```

例えばこのようなデータフレームで下記のようにiatで値を代入しようとすると

```
df1.iat[0,0] = df2.iat[0,0]
```

とすると

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'aaa'

のエラーになりますがilocで

```
df1.iloc[0,0] = df2.iloc[0,0]
```

だと問題なく代入できるのはなぜでしょうか？

Comment: ソースコードを眺めてみると、`iat()` では type casting ができない場合、エラー(ValueError)を送出してお終いになります(exception handling なし)。例えば `np.float64('aaa')` を実行してみると同じエラーが発生します。一方、`iloc()` では ValueError を捕捉して(exception handling あり)、値を入れ替えてしまいます。この場合は `NaN(numpy.float64 type)` が `aaa(str type)` に入れ替わる事になります。

Comment: @metropolis 回答有難うございます。大変勉強になりました。わかりやすい解説有難うございます！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(コメントより)

ソースコードを眺めてみると、`iat()` では type casting ができない場合、エラー(ValueError)を送出してお終いになります(exception handling なし)。例えば `np.float64('aaa')` を実行してみると同じエラーが発生します。一方、`iloc()` では ValueError を捕捉して(exception handling あり)、値を入れ替えてしまいます。この場合は `NaN(numpy.float64 type)` が `aaa(str type)` に入れ替わる事になります。